# How to post to a http page from a https page

Tags: html, forms, http, https

Hi I have a form in my https page but want to post to a http page. How can I do this knowing that https encrypts form data. How do I post it 'plain' in my https page. Thanks

Comment: If you're POSTing to HTTP, you aren't getting any encryption.

Comment: But the data is encrypted since my page is residing on a secured server ,https. But though I have a https page I want to post the data plain like its coming from a non secured page/server